# OOM exception - bitmap size exceeding VM budget

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks

I guess I have a memory leak. 
I have a list activity that uses the camera.... Only working now with taking pictures...
But I guess some list inflating does some of the memory leak...
I guess I missed some resource freeing (guess of images....)

I could not find it.

Really need some help in this one.

Here are the classes:
The List Activity

package org.BJ.Food4All.Activities.NewRecipe;

```
import org.BJ.Food4All.R;
import org.BJ.Food4All.Recipe;
import org.BJ.Food4All.Recipe.Instruction;
import org.BJ.Food4All.Activities.RecipeBook.RecipeInstructionsListViewAdapter;
import org.BJ.Food4All.Activities.RecipeBook.SharedData;
import org.BJ.Food4All.utils.CameraUtil;
import org.BJ.Food4All.utils.ImageUploadItem;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Instructions extends ListActivity implements OnClickListener
{
    private final static String                 mTAG                    = "Instructions";
    private EditText                            mInstructionEditText    = null;
    private RecipeInstructionsListViewAdapter   mListViewAdapter        = null;
    private Recipe                              mEditRecipe             = PrivateResources.GetRecipe();

    private CameraUtil                          mCameraUtil             = new CameraUtil( this );

    private int                                 mSelectedEntryIndex     = -1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState )
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView( R.layout.new_recipe_instruction_tab );

        mInstructionEditText        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.newRecipeInstructionEditTextId);
        View addInstructionButton   = findViewById( R.id.naddInstructionButtonId );

        // Sanity check
        if( mInstructionEditText    == null ||
            addInstructionButton    == null )
        {
            Log.e( mTAG, "NULL pointers");
            // secure exit
            finish();
        }

        // Set up click listeners for all the buttons
        addInstructionButton.setOnClickListener( this );

        mListViewAdapter    = new RecipeInstructionsListViewAdapter(    this, 
                                                                        R.layout.recipes_instruction_list_single_view_entry,
                                                                        mEditRecipe.GetInstructions() );

        setListAdapter( mListViewAdapter );

        registerForContextMenu( getListView() );
    }

    public void onClick( View v )
    {
        switch( v.getId() )
        {
            case R.id.naddInstructionButtonId:
                AddInstructionToRecipe( v );
                break;

            default:
                Log.e( mTAG, "Invalid ID:" + v.getId() );
                // secure exit
                finish();

        }
    }

    private void AddInstructionToRecipe( View v )
    {
        String instructionText = mInstructionEditText.getText().toString();

        if( instructionText == null )
        {
            return;
        }

        Instruction newInstruction = new Instruction(   mEditRecipe.GetInstructions().size() + 1,   // Index
                                                        instructionText,                            // The instruction
                                                        null,
                                                        true );

        if( mEditRecipe.AddInstruction( newInstruction ) != true )
        {
            // TODO - ERROR
        }
        else
        {
            mListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onCreateContextMenu(android.view.ContextMenu, android.view.View, android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo)
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(    ContextMenu     menu, 
                                        View            v,
                                        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) 
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.instructions_ctx_menu, menu);

        super.onCreateContextMenu(  menu, 
                                    v, 
                                    menuInfo );
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        super.onContextItemSelected(item);

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo;
        menuInfo = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        mSelectedEntryIndex = menuInfo.position;

        switch( item.getItemId() ) 
        {
            case R.id.deleteId:
                mEditRecipe.RemoveInstruction( mSelectedEntryIndex );
                mListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

            case R.id.takePictureId:
                mCameraUtil.TakePicture();
                return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.app.Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(    int     requestCode, 
                                        int     resultCode, 
                                        Intent  data ) 
    {
        String imageLocation = mCameraUtil.onActivityResult(    requestCode, 
                                                                resultCode, 
                                                                data );
        // TODO - switch to parameter passed in the intent!!!! like TakePicture( index );
        mEditRecipe.GetInstructions().get( mSelectedEntryIndex ).SetInstructionImageLocation( imageLocation );
        mSelectedEntryIndex = -1;

        // Update the listviewitem with the picture
        mListViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The Adapter:

```
package org.BJ.Food4All.Activities.RecipeBook;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.BJ.Food4All.R;
import org.BJ.Food4All.Recipe.Instruction;
import org.BJ.Food4All.utils.GlobalDefs;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RecipeInstructionsListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Instruction> 
{
    private     Context                         mContext;
    private     ArrayList<Instruction>          mItems;
    private     LayoutInflater                  mInflater;

    public RecipeInstructionsListViewAdapter(   Context                 context,
                                                int                     textViewResourceId, 
                                                ArrayList<Instruction>  items) 
    {
        super(  context, 
                textViewResourceId, 
                items );

        mContext    = context;
        mItems      = items;

        mInflater   = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(    int         position, 
                            View        convertView, 
                            ViewGroup   parent ) 
    {
          ViewHolder    holder = new ViewHolder();

          if (convertView == null) 
          {
              convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.recipes_instruction_list_single_view_entry, null);
          }

          if( super.getItem(position) != null )
          {
              holder.instructionIndex   = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.listUp_RecipeInstructionNumberTextBoxId );
              holder.instructionText    = (TextView) convertView.findViewById( R.id.listUp_RecipeInstructioTextTextBoxId );
              holder.instructionImage   = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById( R.id.listUp_RecipeInstructionImageViewId );

              Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "Eras_Bold.ttf");
              holder.instructionIndex.setTypeface(tf);
              holder.instructionIndex.setTextSize(30);
              holder.instructionIndex.setTextColor( GlobalDefs.GetHeadlineColor() );
              holder.instructionIndex.setText( Integer.toString(mItems.get(position).getIndex() ) );

              tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "Arial.ttf");
              holder.instructionText.setTypeface(tf);
              holder.instructionText.setTextSize(14);
              holder.instructionText.setTextColor( Color.BLACK );
              holder.instructionText.setText( mItems.get(position).getText() );

              String imageLocation = mItems.get(position).GetInstructionImageLocation();
              if( imageLocation != null )
              {
                  holder.instructionImage.setImageURI( Uri.parse( imageLocation ) );
                  holder.instructionImage.setVisibility( View.VISIBLE );
              }
              else
              {
                  holder.instructionImage.setVisibility( View.GONE );
              }

              convertView.setTag(holder);
              convertView.setLayoutParams( new ListView.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
          } 
          else 
          {
          }

          return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int position) 
    {
        return true;
    }

    static class ViewHolder 
    {
          TextView  instructionIndex;
          TextView  instructionText;
          ImageView instructionImage;
    }
}
```

The camera util:

```
package org.BJ.Food4All.utils;

import java.io.File;

import org.BJ.Food4All.DB.DBManager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
//import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraUtil
{
    private static final String mTAG = "CameraUtil";

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE                             = 1;
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE    = 2;

    private Activity        mParentActivity = null;
    private String          mFileName       = null;     // Storage filename
//  private Uri             mImageUri       = null;     // mImageUri is the current activity attribute, define and save it for later usage (also in onSaveInstanceState)
    private Bitmap          mBitmap         = null;
//  private ImageView       mImageView      = null;

    private DBManager       mDBManager      = null;

    public CameraUtil( Activity parentActivity )
    {
        mParentActivity = parentActivity;
        mDBManager      = new DBManager( parentActivity );
    }

    /**
     * Used by the camera button - for taking a new picture
     */
    public void TakePicture() 
    {
        mFileName                   = mDBManager.GetCurrentImageFilename() + ".jpg";
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        contentValues.put( MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE,       mFileName );
        contentValues.put( MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image capture by camera" ); // TODO- update description for recipe name description

//      mImageUri = mParentActivity.getContentResolver().insert(
//                          MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
//                          contentValues );

        //create new Camera Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent( MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
        intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,           Uri.fromFile(getImageFile( mFileName )));//mImageUri );
        intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY,    1 );

        try
        {
            mParentActivity.startActivityForResult( intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE );
        }
        catch( Exception e )
        {
            Toast.makeText( mParentActivity.getApplicationContext(),
                            "Error while starting Camera!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

            Log.e( mTAG, "Failed to start camera" );
            Log.e( mTAG, e.getMessage(), e );
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param requestCode
     * @param resultCode
     * @param data
     */
    public String onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {
        String fileManagerString = null;
        String selectedImagePath = null;
        switch( requestCode ) 
        {
            case PICK_IMAGE:
                // Used if we want to choose a picture from the gallery
                if( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) 
                {
                    Uri     selectedImageUri    = data.getData();
                    String  filePath            = null;

                    try 
                    {
                        // OI FILE Manager
                        fileManagerString = selectedImageUri.getPath();

                        // MEDIA GALLERY
                        selectedImagePath = getPath( selectedImageUri );

                        if( selectedImagePath != null ) 
                        {
                            filePath = selectedImagePath;
                        } 
                        else if( fileManagerString != null ) 
                        {
                            filePath = fileManagerString;
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            Toast.makeText( mParentActivity.getApplicationContext(), 
                                            "Unknown path",
                                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                            Log.e( mTAG, "Unknown image path");
                        }

                        if( filePath != null ) 
                        {
                            DecodeFile( filePath );
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            mBitmap = null;
                        }
                    } 
                    catch( Exception e ) 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText( mParentActivity.getApplicationContext(), 
                                        "Internal error",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                        Log.e( mTAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                }
                break;

            case CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE:
                if( resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) 
                {
//                  Uri     selectedImageUri    = mImageUri;
                    String  filePath            = null;

                    try 
                    {
                        // OI FILE Manager
                        fileManagerString = mFileName;//selectedImageUri.getPath();

                        // MEDIA GALLERY
//                      selectedImagePath = mFileName;//getPath( selectedImageUri );

                        //GlobalData.setUploadedImagePath(selectedImagePath);
    // TODO - for uploading the image
                        // Add image to the recipe images
//                      ImageUploadItem uploadItem = new ImageUploadItem( selectedImagePath );
//                      GlobalData.imageUploads.add(uploadItem);

                        // Get image path on the image
//                      if( selectedImagePath != null ) 
//                      {
//                          filePath = selectedImagePath;
//                      } 
//                      else if( fileManagerString != null ) 
//                      {
                            filePath = fileManagerString;
//                      } 
//                      else 
//                      {
//                          
//                          Toast.makeText( mParentActivity.getApplicationContext(), 
//                                          "Unknown path",
//                                          Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
//                          
//                          Log.e( mTAG, "Unknown image path" );
//                      }

                        if( filePath != null ) 
                        {
                            String p = getImageFile( mFileName ).getPath();
                            DecodeFile( p );//filePath );
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            mBitmap = null;
                        }
                    } 
                    catch( Exception e ) 
                    {
                        Toast.makeText( mParentActivity.getApplicationContext(), 
                                        "Internal error",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();

                        Log.e( mTAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                    }
                }
                break;

            default:
                return null;
        }

        // TODO Here is where the image is received from either the camera or the gallery and is in the async task
        // TODO to go the next activity
        return getImageFile( mFileName ).getPath();//mFileName;//selectedImagePath;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param uri
     * @return
     */
    private String getPath( Uri uri ) 
    {
        String[]    projection  = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor      cursor      = mParentActivity.managedQuery( uri, 
                                                                projection, 
                                                                null, 
                                                                null, 
                                                                null );
        if( cursor != null ) 
        {
            // HERE YOU WILL GET A NULLPOINTER IF CURSOR IS NULL
            // THIS CAN BE, IF YOU USED OI FILE MANAGER FOR PICKING THE MEDIA
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow( MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA );

            cursor.moveToFirst();

            return cursor.getString( column_index );
        } 
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param filePath
     */
    private void DecodeFile( String filePath ) 
    {
        // Decode image size
        BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        bitmapOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeFile( filePath, bitmapOptions );

        // The new size we want to scale to
        final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 1024;

        // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
        int width_tmp   = bitmapOptions.outWidth;
        int height_tmp  = bitmapOptions.outHeight;
        int scale       = 1;

        while( true )
        {
            if( width_tmp   < REQUIRED_SIZE && 
                height_tmp  < REQUIRED_SIZE )
            {
                break;
            }
            width_tmp   /= 2;
            height_tmp  /= 2;
            scale       *= 2;
        }

        // Decode with inSampleSize
        BitmapFactory.Options newBitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

        newBitmapOptions.inSampleSize = scale;

        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile( filePath, newBitmapOptions );
    }

    /**
     * Gets the picture taken by the camera - to be used in ImageView
     * 
     * @return
     */
    public Bitmap GetTakenPictureBitmap()
    {
        return mBitmap;
    }

    /**
     * Get the image FILE to be used for the picture taken by the camera - from filename String
     * 
     * @param filename  - the filename String
     * @return  The File representing the image file
     */
    private File getImageFile( final String filename )
    {
          //it will return /sdcard/image.tmp
          final File path = new File(   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), 
                                        mParentActivity.getPackageName() );
          if( !path.exists() )
          {
              path.mkdir();
          }

          return new File( path, filename );
        }
}
```

Comment: Use SO search .... This question was asked many times ....

Comment: Include the stack trace please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you are holding on to references to `Bitmap` objects, and/or not `recycle()`-ing them promptly when done with them. This causes 99% of such errors.